# files are saved repeatedly with single name, no looping, no ranging

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-os

My codes runs well, but have one flaw. They are not saving accordingly. For example, Let's say I caught 3 jpeg files, when I ran the codes, it saves 3 times on slot 1, 3 times on slot 2, and 3 times on slot 3. So I ended up with 3 same files.

I think there is something wrong with my looping logic? 
If I changed `for n in range(len(soup_imgs)):` to `for n in range(len(src)):`, the operation saves infinitely of the last jpeg files.

```
soup_imgs = soup.find(name='div', attrs={'class':'t_msgfont'}).find_all('img', alt="", src=re.compile(".jpg"))
for i in soup_imgs:
    src = i['src']
    print(src)

dirPath = "C:\\__SPublication__\\" 
img_folder = dirPath + '/' + soup_title + '/'
if (os.path.exists(img_folder)):
    pass
else:
    os.mkdir(img_folder)

for n in range(len(src)):
    n += 1
    img_name = dirPath + '/' + soup_title + '/' + str({}).format(n) + '.jpg'
    img_files = open(img_name, 'wb')
    img_files.write(requests.get(src).content)
    print("Outputs：" + img_name)
```

I am amateur in coding, just started not long ago as a hobby of mine. Please give me some guidance, chiefs.

Comment: Where does the `soup_title` variable come from? I've added an answer, but this variable sticks out as being undefined given the code you have provided.

Comment: sorry about that, it's not the full coding, I just pasted where the problems are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this when you are writing your image files:

```
from os import path

for i, img in enumerate(soup_imgs):
    src = img['src']
    img_name = path.join(dirPath, soup_title, "{}.jpg".format(i))
    with open(img_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(src).content)
    print("Outputs：{}".format(img_name))
```

You need to loop over all image sources, rather than using the last `src` value from a previous `for` block.

I've also added a safer method for joining directory and file paths that should be OS independent. Finally, when opening a file, always use the `with open() as f:` construct - this way Python will automatically close the filehandle for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, "enumerate" function perfectly separated all the chunked img links. I still have so much to learn. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: i found something interesting, why is the saving order is from bottom up? last first is the python logic?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be the case at all. The first file in `soup_imgs` will be the first to be saved.